# Moving transfer help!

Tags: wallet

I just got a bitcoin qt wallet today and I have already sent the money, it is taking to long to to though so if I dump my key and import it to an e-wallet like blockchain.info, will my coins still show up?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the transaction is in the network (it has been transmitted without double spends), you can access your bitcoins with the private key from any client, be it Standard Client, blockchain.info or anything else. Your money is not stored in your wallet, but in the Bitcoin Network - only the private key that lets you access that money is stored in the wallet file.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you mean that the client is taking a long time to synchronize.  If you exported the key and imported it into an e-wallet (or even just a wallet that was already synced), you should see your coins immediately.

You could also download a bootstrap.dat, which may speed up synchronization of the blockchain.  There is a download at http://archive.org/details/bitcoin_bootstrap.dat if you want to try it.